# Weight policy for imbalanced tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, classification, weighted

I want to train a tensorflow DNNClassifier model from an imbalanced dataset. Each sample have a 'quality' value that's represents relative relevance of sample. I assume I can use weight to represent this relevance. I read weights features are multiplicated with loss. In this case 'good' samples may have a low weight. Is it exact ?

Comment: "good" samples meant I want to favorize them, so i have to overweight. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "good samples"? In an imbalanced case, you would have 2 kinds of samples ones that are more in number and ones that are less in number.

The weight for the ones that are more should be less and for the ones that are less should be more.  We are basically making the model focus more on the small number of samples by inflating their losses.

Answer (score 0):

As Pankaj Kabra correctly pointed out, it is not clear what you mean for "good" samples. If you wanted to give them more importance you should weight these examples more; on the contrary, if these are the most numerous samples and you don't want the network to be biased toward them just because there are more, then you need to weight them less.

The most classic approaches for doing this are two:

1. multiplay the per-sample loss for weight according to its class. This means that if you are evaluating the loss on the more numerous class, you must multiply its value for smaller weight; vice-versa, if you are dealing with the smallest class then the weight must be bigger. For example you can use weights computed as: `w_class = 1.0/(number_of_samples_for_this_class)`.
2. sample balanced mini-batches, where the numerosity of the two classes is the same.